# Which programming language for consuming / producing message in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to create a service which is only consuming and producing message for Kafka.

I looked into with for a while and I want some opinions which language would be the most suitable for implementing this. Of course I know it is possible in every language but e.g I am not convinced writing this service in PHP.

I already checked for Java / Kotlin and Go

Comment: The choice of language depends on your familiarity and preferences, as well as the specific requirements of your project. Consider factors such as the size of your team, the ecosystem and community support, performance requirements, and any existing codebase or infrastructure considerations when making your decision.

Comment: @AlenPaulVarghese well it's project on my own so there no real strict requirements besides my own decisions.